# why camera from my doc is different to the example

Tags: flame

I followed a tutorial and code looks like this:

```
class MyGame extends Forge2DGame{
  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    camera.toString(); // <= this camera is a Vector2
  }
}
```

But what I learned from another tutorial is like this:

```
class SpacescapeGame extends FlameGame{
  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    camera.shake(); // <= this camera is a Camera class
  }
}
```

What I understand is Forge2DGame extends BaseGame, BaseGame extends FlameGame https://pub.dev/documentation/bonfire/latest/base_base_game/BaseGame-class.html

but why I cant use camera.shake as second tutorial showed? thank you for your explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you read the [Flame documentation](https://flame-engine.org/docs/) instead of the bonfire documentation if you want to write a Flame game that is not involving bonfire.

The camera for `Forge2DGame` is the same camera as is used for `FlameGame`, you have most likely added some other variable that is also called `camera` which is shadowing the real camera.

Also make sure that you are on the latest version of flame (`1.4.0`) and the latest version of flame_forge2d (`0.12.3`).

Comment: Hi spydon, thank you for your comment, you are right, after update flutter and flame, I saw the right camera class... I will set this as right answer.

Comment: Now I just need to figure out how to exchange expired import source, since lots of them have changed the name, such as import 'package:flame_forge2d/viewport.dart'; Is no longer existing.. could you please let me know usually how to figure out this changing? Through pub.dev changelog? thank for your further guidance, Im new to the code world.

Comment: It should be enough to just use `import 'package:flame_forge2d/flame_forge2d.dart';`